# Issue while fetching dates between range

Tags: mysql, database, between

I have two tables. One is hall which is having following schema.
[image: Hall Table]

[image: Events Table]

One hall can have many events.I want halls which are available between two dates.For example halls between 2016-09-10 and enddate = 2016-09-15. 
I want all the halls which are not booked for the whole range of dates i.e 10,11,12,13,14,15.

Comment: Can you show some example data & your exact query & expected results - your 2 scenario are not that enlightening.

Comment: Thanks @PaulF for reply. This scenarios are only examples. I mean to say any hall which has atleast one date available in that range.

Comment: I don't even understand what the scenarios are showing - you need to be much clearer.

Comment: This is the which i tried `SELECT
  h.*
FROM
  halls h
LEFT JOIN
  (
  SELECT
    hallid,id
  FROM EVENTS
WHERE EVENTS.eventdate BETWEEN '2016-10-10' AND '2016-10-15'
GROUP BY
  id
) AS e ON h.id = e.hallid
WHERE
  e.id IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

So what's the problem? (:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM events
INNER JOIN halls ON (halls.id = events.hallid)
WHERE 
  events.eventdate >= '2016-09-10' AND events.eventdate <= '2016-09-15';
```

Comment: This will select the hall which is booked on 10,11,12,13,14,15. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @NishantDongare if hall was booked for defined period - yes

Answer (score 0):

create new column in your inner query having value of daypart from eventdate
then filter the data using not in based on a new column

ex: select t.* from (  select table1 .hallname,table2.eventdate,DAY(table2.eventdate) as daypart from table1 inner join table2 where eventdate between  startdate and enddate) as t where t.daypart not in (select booked eventdate from event table i.e selected by commas)